# ubuntu 18.04 LTS does not detect Samsung Level U

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I have ubuntu 18.04 and it does not detect my Samsung Level U headset. Although it has no trouble detecting my phone and other devices.

I'm sure the headset is working and discover-able because i'm using it with my phone.

Tried to use this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
```

And my device is not there. I also tried scanning with Blueman but it also won't find it.

My Laptop is Acer Aspire VN7-592G.

Any idea about this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that your 16.04 system did correctly pair with the headphones, but your 18.04 system does not?

Comment: No, i just purchased it and I didn't try it with 16.04. That piece of info may be confusing, I'll remove it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:-

1. switch on the Bluetooth on your laptop and headphone
2. press the pairing button(it's present below the volume keys) on your headphone
3. for a few seconds you should be able to see the name of your
   Bluetooth device on your laptop
4. connect it

Comment: Thanks. This helped me out. 
I thought something was wrong with my laptop's bluetooth interface.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have installed Blueman.

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth  
killall pulseaudio
```

Reboot, try Blueman again.